# Why is `ssh` not working after adding public key to authorized hosts?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, pem

I have a cluster set up with a master node and one slave node.  I'd like to ssh to and from the master and slave nodes.

Now, I am able to `ssh` from both my local machine, and from my master node into the slave directly, using my private key: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@<IP>`.  I get asked for a password, and I enter it and can access the slave node from both my local machine, and my dev master.

Ideally, I want to remove my private `id_rsa` key from the `~/.ssh` directory on dev master and only use my public key `id_rsa.pub` to `ssh` back and forth between master and slave nodes.  (this is for security reasons, and plus it shouldn't be that difficult, right?).

So, I added my public key `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys` on the slave node.  Now, when I try to ssh from the master node to the slave it asks me for a password for the `id_rsa.pub`:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ec2-user@<IP>
Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
```

And, I enter the same password I do for `id_rsa` but that password fails. :/  (I also tried just pressing enter (no password)) doesn't work either.

I have two questions to this:

- 1)  Why isn't the password for `id_rsa.pub` the same as `id_rsa`?
- 2)  Why can't I ssh into the slave node using my public key `id_rsa.pub` when it is added to the `authorized_keys` file?

When I try to ssh from my master to my slave, with the public key added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` here is the verbose output:

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv0
debug1: Connecting to <ip> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 792 bytes for a total of 813
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 837
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 138/256
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 981
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host '<ip>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 521/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 997
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1045
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f2d4970bf40)
debug2: key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1109
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address <ip>.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server krbtgt/US-WEST-2.COMPUTE.INTERNAL@host.COM not found in Kerberos database
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1205
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1573
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp df:e5:5b:18:67:05:8b:4d:06:6c:f9:99:c3:b5:2b:9f:4e:f2:52:8a
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: Wrote 640 bytes for a total of 2213
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I don't know why it won't let me ssh into the slave node, when my public key has been added as an `authorized_keys`.

Or, if there is an easier way to `ssh` between master and slave nodes, I'd be open to that as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: yes, I did as per this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110814/server-keeps-asking-for-password-after-ive-copied-my-ssh-public-key-to-authoriz  thank you!!

Comment: Great! Can you upvote my answer then it is the correct answer to your problem! :) Thank you

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 3):

Public and Private keys are lock key pairs. Your public key is not a key but a lock. You can give away that lock to anyone but never your private key. Your server has that lock. As stated in the comment below, you cannot open a lock with a lock. Using `ssh -i privatekey ip@aws` will work. Not `ssh -i publickey ip@aws`.

Comment: I am still having the same problem even after setting those permissions as you have shown me.

Comment: Okay I see, I understand your problem now. Your node has a public key in authorized_keys. Think of public keys as a lock and a private key as key. Only you should have that private key and you cannot open a lock with a lock.  Which you tried by inputting `ssh -i id_rsa.pub ip@aws` You must use a private key to match the public key that's authorized.

Comment: can you plpease edit or delete your answer since it is not relevant?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: By that logic, I need to have my private key `id_rsa` on my dev master in order to `ssh` into the slave.  I don't see this working, because if I allow others (colleagues, etc.), access to my dev master to collaborate, he/she will then have my private `id_rsa` key.  I need to be able to ssh between my master and slave without using my private key `id_rsa` because I don't want to share it with my colleagues.

Comment: If you and your colleagues have different users on the node, you can set permissions to not allow your colleagues to access any of your files.
so basically /home/colleagues/ cannot access /home/you/

Or you can use your local machine to access both your nodes instead of using dev master as a proxy ssh like youre trying.

Comment: Furthermore, using an `id_rsa` requires my password - which my colleagues don't know.  So, they will not be able to use the cluster and ssh between the machines.  I want it to be passwordless to `ssh`` between the master and slave nodes.

Comment: There's a difference between your nodes asking for a password (which is not ) and your private key asking for a password. Your private key is asking for a passphrase that allows you to use the private key. Which isn't bad, it's extra security. But if you want to make it passwordless, generate a new private key and public key without a passphrase, make sure not to override your existing keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139089/discussion-between-simple-and-luis-estevez).

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ec2-user@<IP>
```

You should use private key here. Not the public one. SSH is wrongly [asking passphrase for quite everything](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2522) in few recent version, but it should be fixed now.

> 2) Why can't I ssh into the slave node using my public key id_rsa.pub when it is added to the authorized_keys file?

The keys are probably set up wrong. Run the client and server in debug mode (`LogLevel DEBUG3` in `ssh_confing` and `sshd_config`) and have a look on the logs. If you will not be able to find out from that, update the question with the logs.

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp df:e5:5b:18:67:05:8b:4d:06:6c:f9:99:c3:b5:2b:9f:4e:f2:52:8a
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: Wrote 640 bytes for a total of 2213
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
```

The logs above says that the key was accepted, but it was not enough to grant you access to that server. More information will be visible in the server log.

Comment: I don't have an `sshd_config` file at `/etc/ssh` for some reason.  And, I'm not sure how I would set up the keys any differently.  But anyways, let me post in my question the logs.

Comment: (by the way, you don't need to change the loglevel, you can just do `ssh -vvv <user>@<ip>`)

Comment: I added the comments for the client log. Still the server log will answer the missing questions.